# Integrating Shipping with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

What is the best method to include shipping quotes in my cart?

The basic flow of my site is that

```
1.) User selects products  
2.) User is shown cart  
3.) repeat 1 and 2 until User wants to pay  
4.) collect user details ( email, address where items will be shipped to )  
5.) make payment via active merchant  
6.) order is submitted to distributor.
```

I would like to insert a shipping information, so that the user can pay for his purchase + shipping costs via active merchant.

```
1.) User selects products  
2.) User is shown cart  
3.) repeat 1 and 2 until User wants to pay  
4.) collect user details ( email, address where items will be shipped to )  
5.) calculate the cost of shipment, add cost to cart, show to user;
6.) make payment via active merchant  
7.) order is submitted to distributor.
```

Is there a gem or plugin to help me here, if not... how can I get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the active_shipping gem:

http://github.com/Shopify/active_shipping

Its another extraction from Shopify (like ActiveMerchant)