# Integrating usps api on rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, api, usps, fedex

I want to integrate https://www.usps.com/ and also fedex api on my rails application, but I could not understand their documentation. Is there anybody who can help me? Or can any one provide me an easy tutorial of how it should be integrate on web ? I want to calculate the cost of package or gifts of the users on many condition.

Please note: there is a gem for this sevice but it is too old and the application I am going to build it is on rails 3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try editing your question and pointing to the documentation, this could help you get the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515115/integrating-shipping-with-ruby-on-rails) might be helpful to you. There is this another gem called [fedex](https://github.com/mcmire/fedex) you can look into. Hope this helps.